# read a file of JSON string in pyspark

Tags: json, string, pyspark

I have a file look like this:

```
'{"Name": "John", "Age": 23}'
'{"Name": "Mary", "Age": 21}'
```

How can I read this file and get a pyspark dataframe like this:

```
     Name   | Age
    "John"  | 23
    "Mary"  | 21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read in the file in `text` format, and then use the `from_json` function to convert the row to two columns.

```
df = spark.read.load(path_to_your_file, format='text')
df = df.selectExpr("from_json(trim('\\'' from value), 'Name string,Age int') as data").select('data.*')
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: It works.  Thanks!